# Help with JavaScript scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I fear I may be losing my marbles today, because I don't know how to do what I want to. I want a custom prompt that I can call from any of my other JavaScript functions. I don't know how to get this work, even though it *feels* like I've done it a hundred times.

Here is an example

```
var modal = function() {

    var prompt = function(msg) {
        // custom prompt builder here... let's return hard coded for example's sake
        return true;
    };

}();

var items = function() {
    var init = function() {

        $('.delete').click(function() {
            var confirm = modal.prompt('Are you sure you wanna delete that pal?');
        });

    };    


    $(document).ready(init);    
}();
```

What I want to be able to do is call the prompt method of modal, and get a return value based on the user input. Now this, I can do, but I am having problems calling the inner method. I want to group these together because I will probably have a custom modal `alert()` too.

Please don't suggest the built in JavaScript OK/Cancel as I gotta do this custom.

Many thanks!

Comment: Aside: if you're calling an anonymous function immediately, it's good practice to parenthesize the function. This makes the call more noticeable. If you don't, someone might not notice the trailing `()` an mistake your intent.

Comment: @otis Do you mean wrap the whole thing in an extra pair or parenthesis? I think I have seem that before. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You will not be able to get a return value based on user input anyway,since the script will execute in its entirety (return statement and all) before user interaction gets into the picture. You'll have to use a different flow, that relies on callbacks for this. You will not be able to mimic the native behavior of prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the way you call `modal.prompt`, it appears you want the anonymous function to return an object that will be stored in `modal`:

```
var modal = (function() {
    // various private fields & methods here
    ...
    // the public interface
    var self = {
        prompt: function(msg) {
            // custom prompt builder here... let's return hard coded for example's sake
            return true;
        }
    };
    return self;
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

For your first issue, the `prompt` function, is declared as a variable within your `modal` object, you can't access it because you aren't actually exposing it publicly:

```
var modal = (function() {
  var privateMethod1 = function () {/*...*/},
      privateVar = 'foo';

  function privateMethod2() {
    //...
  }

  return { // public members
    prompt: function (msg) {
      // custom prompt builder here... let's return hard coded for example's sake
      return true;
    }
  };
})();
```

Now for the following issue:

> What I want to be able to do is call the prompt method of modal, and get a return value based on the user input.

The user input is an asynchronous action, I would recommend you to use a callback based model, the built-in  JavaScript OK/Cancel `window.prompt` can actually return a value, because it **stops the code execution** and waits for the user input.

```
var modal = (function() {
    return {
      prompt: function(msg, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
        // ...

        $('#okButton').click(function () {
          // internal actions here, like closing the dialog, cleanup, etc...
          okCallback(); // execute the ok callback
        });

        $('#cancelButton').click(function () {
          // ...
          cancelCallback(); // execute the cancel callback
        });
      }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend anyone who is going to make a habit of writing javascript code read and understand this http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html.

It's critically important.

Comment: +1 Alex may or may not be confusing closures with properties, but it's such a great document.

Comment: The document covers more than closures.  It covers scope in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

> ```
> var modal = {
>     prompt : function(msg) {
>            return true;
>          }
> };
> ```

and then you can cal it like:

> ```
> modal.prompt();
> ```

Comment: I think you mean to suggest:
    var modal = {
        prompt : function(msg) { return true; }
    };